# From a list of sets find how many other (unique) elements an item is paired with, find the most commonly paired one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, set

I’ve got a list of sets, and I’m trying to get the item in the sets that go with most items – not the most common one or the one occurring in most sets, but the one which “interacts” with most items.

Example of the list of sets:

```
food = [{'avocado', 'banana', 'coffee'}, {'avocado', 'donuts'}, {'coffee', 'licorice'}]
```

Should return the item with most interactions, if there's more with the equal value it should return the one that comes first alphabetically, in this case: **avocado**

I've managed to create a dict with the items as keys, and their corresponding 'interactions' as values. Order the dict by max value (well, sorting a list), and finally getting the item with most 'interactions' by indexing the first element in said list.

```
def goes_with_most(food):
    food_type = {}
    for mixture in food:
        for stuff in mixture:
            if stuff not in food_type:
                food_type[stuff] = len(mixture) - 1     #the number of interactions 
            else: food_type[stuff] += (len(mixture) - 1)
    max_value_ls = sorted(food_type.items(), key=lambda stuff: (-stuff [1], stuff[0]))
    return max_value_ls[0][0]                            #returns the first item with the highest value
```

Surely there's a much cleaner solution and would greatly appreciate tips!

Comment: What do you mean by "interact"? Is "x interacts with y" supposed to mean "x and y appear together in a set"?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica it's the amount of time x meets any given variable.

Comment: If x and y appear together in *two* sets, does that count twice, or does that only count as one interaction for each of them?

Comment: Indeed, I was assuming you meant that if you have `{'advocado', 'coffee', 'banana'}` and `{'advocado', 'banana', 'chocolate'}`, that `'advocado'` has 'interacted' with 3 other ingredients: `'banana'`, `'chocolate'` and `'coffee'`, so *three* ingredients. Your code is counting the `'banana'` ingredient **twice**.

Comment: Unrelated: you've got a typo bug, where the argument to the lambda is misspelled `sutff`. That means that the correctly-spelled `stuff` inside the lambda is going to use the binding for that variable from the outer scope, which is left over from the last iteration of the inner `for stuff in mixture` loop.

Comment: Okay, so: the number of "interactions" with `avocado` is: the number of unique elements, except for `avocado` itself, seen in any set that also contains `avocado`?

Comment: @lost_fish it may help out to improve the question by giving a few example of various sets and the expected result you want to get from it. As you can see from other comments people are struggling to understand what you would like to the code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified very clearly what 'interactions' are. I see two possible interpretations:

1. The number of unique ingredients that something is paired with. In a list with `{'advocado', 'coffee', 'banana'}` and `{'advocado', 'banana', 'chocolate'}`, the `'advocado'` is paired with **three** unique ingredients: `'banana'`, `'chocolate'` and `'coffee'`.
2. For each set, the number of other ingredients in that set, regardless of their presence in other sets. In a list with `{'advocado', 'coffee', 'banana'}` and `{'advocado', 'banana', 'chocolate'}`, the `'advocado'` is paired with 2 ingredients in the first, and 2 ingredients in the second, so there are **4** other ingredients it was paired with. That `'banana'` is present in both those sets doesn't matter.

Your code sticks to the second interpretation, and you state that the code already works. I'm giving you code for both.

Either way, you pretty much have the right idea already. You *have* to:

1. find all unique elements
2. find out how many other (unique) elements any of the items in 1. is paired with.

To get 1. you *can't avoid* looping over all input sets and, for each set, all the values.

But first of all: You only need to find the **one** element that wins, so you can use `max()` or `min()`, and do **not** need to sort! Sorting is only useful if you need to know the exact ranking of **all** foods.

To implement the first interpretation, I'd just create unions with the sets, which avoids having to manually loop and test for containment. You end up with sets that have the specific ingredient as both key and the set, but since this applies to *all* ingredients, you still get the correct answers:

```py
def goes_with_most(food):
    ingredients = {}
    for mixture in food:
        for ingredient in mixture:
            ingredients.setdefault(ingredient, set()).update(mixture)
    return min(ingredients, key=lambda ing: (-len(ingredients[ing]), ing))
```

Note the sort key here: we are not looking for the largest but are instead using the *negative set size*, with the food name as tie breaker. For `advocado` this returns `(-4, 'advocado')`, which sorts before `(-4, 'coffee')`, so keeps the names alphabetically sorted.

You already used that trick, but it bears making explicit, and it works for `min()` just as much as it does for sorting.

Demo:

```py
>>> food = [{'avocado', 'banana', 'coffee'}, {'avocado', 'donuts'}, {'coffee', 'licorice'}]
>>> goes_with_most(food)
'avocado'
```

The second interpretation, which is what you implemented, just needs to replace the sets with integers:

```py
def goes_with_most(food):
    counts = {}
    for mixture in food:
        for ingredient in mixture:
            counts[ingredient] = counts.get(ingredient, 0) + len(mixture) - 1
    return min(counts, key=lambda ing: (-counts[ing], ing))
```

We can make this slightly shorter (not needing a `dict.get(key, 0)`) by using a [`defaultdict` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def goes_with_most(food):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for mixture in food:
        for ingredient in mixture:
            counts[ingredient] += len(mixture) - 1
    return min(counts, key=lambda ing: (-counts[ing], ing))
```

Comment: Indeed, it is about how many other (unique) elements an item is paired with! Thus you were correct with your interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```
def goes_with_most(food):
    max_counter = -1
    food_type = {}
    for mixture in food:
        for item in mixture:
            if item not in food_type:
                food_type[item] = 0
            food_type[item] += 1
            max_counter = max(food_type[item], max_counter)
    for item in sorted(food_type.keys()):
        if food_type[item] == max_counter:
            return item
```

or shorter

```
def goes_with_most(food):
    items = []
    for f in food:
        items.extend(list(f))
    counter = collections.Counter(items)
    return sorted([i[0] for i in counter.items() if i[1] == max(counter.values())])[0]
```

Comment: my code already works, I'm looking for a shorter solution. But thanks!

Comment: added a shorter version :)

Comment: Your shorter function added quadratic runtime performance (as the input size increases, time taken increases exponentially).  Why sort **at all**? At most, use `max()` once, then use `min()` on the subset of  Ames with the same maximum count.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, here is what I think is an elegant and simple approach.

First: what food items are there? We simply take all of those "meal" sets and mash them together into a single set - after all, duplicates will be removed:

```
menu = [{'avocado', 'banana', 'coffee'}, {'avocado', 'donuts'}, {'coffee', 'licorice'}]

foods = set.union(*menu)
```

Now, let's write a function to find out how many food items are compatible with a given food. We'll count the food itself for this; this means one more item than in the problem description, but *consistently* one more for *every* item, so it does not affect the sorting. We simply grab all the "meals" that include the food and make a sub-menu with them, and see how many food items it has:

```
def compatibility(menu, food):
    meals = [meal for meal in menu if food in meal]
    return len(set.union(*meals))
```

Now we can simply get the best of the `foods` according to their `compatibility` and name. The tricky part is that we want to grab the highest compatibility, but "lowest" string at that compatibility level. We can't "negate" the string, so instead I negate the compatibility, and then look for the smallest value for negative-compatibility.

So:

```
min(foods, key=lambda f: (-compatibility(menu, f), f)) # 'avocado'
```

Comment: The OP had an O(NlogN) implementation, without the sort it could have been a simple O(N) operation. Why expand this to N**2?

Comment: Note that you have picked the first of two possible interpretations (see my answer) while the OP implemented the second interpretation and stated that their code works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of solving this with list comprehensions, based on my understanding of what you mean by 'interactions'.

```
food = [{'avocado', 'banana', 'coffee'}, 
        {'avocado', 'donuts'}, 
        {'coffee', 'licorice'}]


def f(j): return sum([len(i)-1 for i in food if j in i])

unique_stuff = set.union(*food) #Borrowed from @Karl, as his is more efficient
goes_with_most = max([(i, f(i)) for i in unique_stuff], key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
goes_with_most
```

```
'avocado'
```

**The goal here is just to get a 'cleaner' more readable solution, not the most efficient.**

If you are interested in the most efficient, Benchmarks -

1. @Akshay Sehgal - 5.02 µs ± 489 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2. @Karl Knechtel - 5.83 µs ± 953 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
3. @Daniel Meltzer - 4.75 µs ± 609 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
4. @Martijn Pieters♦ - 3.73 µs ± 537 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: This is super inefficient, doing the work in N**2 steps where only N are needed.

Comment: you mean the sort? i have fixed that.

Comment: No, the sort is only O(NlogN).  For every food you call `f()` which iterates over `food` in full for every ingredient. Try to scale up the number of ingredients and sets; generate 100, 1000, etc. Your solution is going to get really slow real fast as the input grows.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it clearly, I was only providing a `cleaner` solution, and that if OP needs an efficient one, he could refer to others.